# Opposite of Stateless Protocol?

Tags: protocols, stateless

I would like to know what the opposite of a 'stateless protocol' is.  Am I correct in assuming that, seeing as HTTP is stateless, for example, then a protocol such as FTP is the opposite/one that maintains state?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are stateless protocols (like http) and stateful protocols (like ftp, telnet, ...).

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) :

> In computing, a stateless protocol is a communications protocol that treats each request as an independent transaction that is unrelated to any previous request so that the communication consists of independent pairs of requests and responses. A stateless protocol does not require the server to retain session information or status about each communications partner for the duration of multiple requests.

According to this [article](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/shri/State.html) - Stateful protocol :

> The client connects to the server, conducts a series of operations via that conneciton, and then disconnects.Then server can associate all of the requests together and knows that thy all came from the same user.

Answer (score 3):

Statefull protocol is a protocol designed to keep state in each step, meaning that a statefull server is aware of previous requests.
Stateless protocol do not keep state. Each request is a like it is a new request.
State can be build into stateless protocols.
E.g. HTTP is a stateless protocol, but due to needs state can be kept using cookies, session data etc